# How can I modify a particular element of this LaTeX template?

Tags: beamer

I am currently looking at this template giving me this display below:

[image]

As you can see the footer of this has my name followed by my university. The field is too big. Now I want to modify it within my LaTeX file given in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/sd12832/d4cf013c12a43ecda281bb6f5522b86c) here.

Is this theme specific? Can I still modify it in that case?

Comment: Try with `\institute[SJSU]{San Jose State University}` or replace SJSU with whatever shorter name you want for your institute. Almost all these commands have an optional parameter for shorter names to be included in footers, ...

Comment: @Ignasi where exactly should I add the `\institute[SJSU]{San Jose State University}`?  Would it be at the very start of the file?

Comment: You already have this line in your text. Replace line 57: `\institute{San Jose State University}` by `\institule[SJSU]{san Jose State University}`.

Comment: @SharanDuggirala Can you please edit your question so it does not rely on third party sites?

Comment: @samcarter done

Comment: @Ignasi If you put this down as an answer, I can accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some fragments from section *10 Structuring a Presentation: The Static Global Structure* in [`beameruserguide`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/beamer):

[image]

[image]

As you can see reading this section almost all commands used to define the title page and structure (`\section`, `\subsection`, ...) are defined with an optional parameter called `short title|author name|institue|...`. These shorts versions are used in footlines and headlines but only when they are defined. Otherwise long names are used.

Therefore if you replace your institution name `\institute{San Jose State University}` by `\institute[SJSU]{San Jose State University}` the short name 
`SJSU` will be used in footline.